# Make a class extend a generic class with certain types w/o resupplying them using decorators

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript3.0

I want to make a class extend another class with a certain generic type where the types is being supplied by a decorator. I want to transfer the types from the decorator to be used in the abstract class MutatorBase. The reason I can't just skip the decorator and just extend the abstract class is because I need to get the constructor of the classes/types provided.

This is what im trying to achieve:

```js
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
type ObjectTuple = readonly Constructor<unknown>[];

function Mutator<T extends ObjectTuple>(...objs: T) {
    return <U extends MutatorBase<T>>(mutator: U) => {
      // do meta stuff
  };
}

abstract class MutatorBase<T extends ObjectTuple = []> {
    mutate(fn: (objs: T) => void) {
        // get objects
        // call fn(objs);
    }
}

class ObjectExample {
    data: number = 0;
}

@Mutator(ObjectExample)
class MutatorExample extends MutatorBase {

}
```

This doesn't work, as the decorator can't find the function `mutate` even though the class extends `MutatorBase`. Also, the types provided in the decorator is probably not transferred aswell.

Now `MutatorExample extends MutatorBase<[typeof ObjectExample]>` would fix the issue but requires me to supply the objects a second time which is something I want to avoid.

Is this possible to do in any way?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but the problem is that the function returned by `Mutator(ObjectExample)` expects its input to be an *instance* of  `MutatorBase<ObjectExample>`, but you are calling it on a *constructor*.  So maybe you want `(mutator: Constructor<MutatorBase<T>>)` instead?  But of course that leads to further issues.

Comment: I mean, [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqAfFALxQIQDuUAFAHSMCGqA5kgFxRMIgDaAXQCUZEgQDcAKFCQoAeQBGAKwjYC6MABto5VBCYATRJpCxEKDNlx50CANYI4VBEUFSAZrewBLRFACy6MBMOPgEUBAAHsAQCAZI8sqqwOpaEEQMjHDKnFAEIgDeklAlUHrA6KgIUHgAqhHRsfFmyGhYoXiBwaEAQkxIEIREw7QAtkEhuFy1IqQkRaVQAL5SS5JMChZM2FCYmv0JXZOofQOEDTFxCYoqahraZFCC88Wl490QtO4IXLTZSrl8qIoAA3ODeAyFV4lNZrPYHRK3YAAUUiTFGaSgC1KBhCTC4CHQowUEFQjwADKtJAABI6hWg3ZKo9FpISSeFIQ4TULMjEPKKXZp03CnQZ8GQQODuRFMtF8iACF5LIA) at least *compiles*, but I'm still not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: What im trying to do is to not require adding the generics to the MutatorBase, but instead get the types from the decorator parameter.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get the types"?  Where will you use these types?  Note that [decorators do not affect class types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) so the type system won't see the results of `@Mutator(ObjectExample)` anywhere.

Comment: Get the types as in when calling `this.mutate(objs => {})` from the decorated class the objs parameter will be typed accordingly to the decorator param. But if the type system cant extract the decorator types maybe its not possible?

Comment: Trying to do this with decorators is probably not possible.  You might be able to use some sort of mixin function instead that is declared to take a class constructor and return a new class constructor, but I don't know how best to advise.